# Wordpress: How to position a custom widget in the top of the widget list in admin panel?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm writing a wordpress theme now and i just can't figure out how to position the widgets in the admin panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the sidebar in the Wordpress admin panel, you can use a very simple plugin - [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/). It's drag-and-drop plugin, so you can make your menu really easy.
[image]

Comment: no i'm not talking about the sidebar. i mean the widget list in admin panel. i think i need to edit my question and add a image

Comment: i've just added the image.

Comment: Now I see.... Unfortunately I never did this in Wordpress, but I found some useful information from the Wordpress Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API

Comment: Dashboard widgets are the widgets we see in the front page of wordpress, these aren't the widgets in the appearance part. But anyway,thanks.)